# pycharm- AttributeError: module 'sysconfig' has no attribute '_get_default_scheme'

Tags: python, pycharm

[image: 1]

I tried to upgrade my python version from 3.7.9 to 3.10.8 and tried to create a new project in pycharm and got this error:
pycharm- AttributeError: module 'sysconfig' has no attribute '_get_default_scheme'

how to fix this issue

I tried to upgrade my python version from 3.7.9 to 3.10.8 and tried to create a new project in pycharm

Comment: go ask in jetbrains forums

Comment: @drum where is that? any link?

Comment: here's the link: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200379535-PyCharm

Comment: Do no link images in questions. Either include in the question, but I assume you can just copy the text (which help you and us to reproduce the problem, and to answer, without need to read and type again your code [we are volunteers, so do not expect many of us will use time for such things]). And do you think programmers open random links from random people? (and if you do not have time to add something better for us instead of `enter image description here`, why should we take time for you?).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the only way was to create the virtualenv manually from command line (removing the venv folder previously created)

```
python3.10 -m venv venv
```

and then activate it `source venv/bin/activate`

After configure pycharm to use the existing python interpreter it is still blaming that the interpreter is not supported but is able to activate and use the virtual environment created